# 'Expected `model` argument to be a `Model` instance, got keras object

Tags: keras

I am trying to use TPU on colab,

```
model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss='binary_crossentropy',
              metrics=[auc])

model = tf.contrib.tpu.keras_to_tpu_model(
        model,
        strategy=tf.contrib.tpu.TPUDistributionStrategy(

tf.contrib.cluster_resolver.TPUClusterResolver(TPU_ADDRESS)))
```

I got the following error.

Expected `model` argument to be a `Model` instance, got `<keras.engine.training.Model object at 0x7f8e828822e8>`

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try convert the un-compiled model to TPU model first, then compile the TPU model.

Like in this medium article I've found. https://medium.com/the-artificial-impostor/keras-for-tpus-on-google-colaboratory-free-7c00961fed69

And here's the google colab link https://colab.research.google.com/gist/ceshine/f196d6b030adb1ec3a8d0b50642709dc/keras-fashion-mnist-tpu.ipynb#scrollTo=pWEYmd_hIWg8